# Please help identify this anime or OVA from 14 years ago about magic

Tags: doomed-megalopolis

OK this is a long shot as I only remember two scenes. It's just stuck with me and I would be very interested in finding out what anime it was. I saw it about 14 (maybe 15) years ago and I don't know if it was new then or not (probably not anime was never a big thing in the UK back then). I think I saw it on the Bravo channel but I'm guessing as it was the only channel willing to show anime that had anything remotely interesting (other channels had heavily edited Kiddy stuff).

The first scene I remember was a stand-off from two wizards (or magic users). One was an old man on the ground, I think he had white hair. He was facing an evil wizard who was levitating some distance away (yet they could hear other as they always seem to do in anime). The old wizard shot some kind of magic arrow that he seemed very certain would kill this evil wizard but the evil wizard blocked it with the palm of his hand which was in a white glove with an up-side-down pentagram. The old wizard clutched then clutched his heart, bleeding as if struck by the arrow (which was still in the evil wizard's hand who seemed unaffected by this), shocked at what had happened, and then fell down, presumably dead. The old wizard laughed.

The other scene was of some woman, supposedly important but I can't remember why - I think the evil wizard wanted her for something? She was writhing in pain on the floor. It's daylight and they'd in a meadow or plains (short grass and where she rolled there was just dirt). She stops writhing but continues shaking and starts wretching, heaving. Suddenly something pokes out from her mouth and starts coming out of her, it ends up being a giant white-pink maggot which promptly wriggles away. She survives the ordeal and lays there shaking, recovering. There's a voice over of two men who I think were with her but not showing at the time. One is younger asking what happened and one is older (possibly the old wizard I mentioned earlier) explained she gave birth to a maggot and this was due to dark magic. Oddly, neither seem surprised by the fact there is a maggot almost the size of an adult human or concerned that the maggot might become a giant fly (which are annoying pests when tiny and swattable - a giant fly is just... Ick).

From the haziness of my memory I am not sure what kind of setting it is. The clothing is all simple but also something you'd expect in older Japan - robes and basic plain cloth type. I don't recall the buildings but I think it is pre-machine times so I don't think there's cars or guns.

The animation style has that older grittier texture to it which all the older anime seem to have - something between Violence Jack and CyberCity Oeda 808. I think it was a movie/OVA rather than a series but I may be mistaken. I get the impression it was a "not for kids" kind of anime (even though I was a kid at the time) but I'm guessing on that because back then those were the only ones I watched (except for Vampire Princess Miyu) and because it was an 'after 10pm watershed' thing.

I don't really have much more detail than this I am sorry but it stayed with me and can't seem to find it when I do my searches. If you could help at all it would be appreciated. If you solve this you will have my undying gratitude and I'd even give you my last rolo if I actually ate those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like **Doomed Megalopolis**.

[image]

(From Wikipedia):

> Doomed Megalopolis (帝都物語 Teito Monogatari?) is a supernatural/dark fantasy anime. It is an adaptation of the historical fantasy novel Teito Monogatari by Hiroshi Aramata. The anime is darker, more violent and sexualized than any previous adaptations of the novel; an artistic decision probably inspired by the financial success of the OVA Legend of the Overfiend. Like its live-action predecessor, Tokyo: The Last Megalopolis, the anime is only an adaptation of the first 1/3rd (the first four books) of the original novel.
>
> It was released by Toei in 1991 as a 4-part OVA. In 1995, ADV Films gained the rights to the anime and released it on a four-volume cassette series in the US, under the title Doomed Megalopolis. In 2001, ADV re-released the entire series on a 2-Disc DVD edition. However, this release did not have the original Japanese soundtrack or any special features. Eventually, ADV gathered the rights to the original Japanese voices, and in 2003, re-released an enhanced version entitled Doomed Megalopolis: Special Edition, wherein the Japanese language option was available and bonus features, such as interviews and documentaries were added.[

It's around the right time frame, though it's not listed under the programs broadcasted by Bravo.

The main antagonist is an evil wizard with white gloves with a pentagram on it, and in the beginning of the movie, he blocks the arrow:

[image]

The start of the movie has this old guy:

[image]

There's also this scene:

[image]

More info:

- [My Anime List](http://myanimelist.net/anime.php?id=1148)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomed_Megalopolis)
- [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=304)

Comment: **That's it!** Thank you so much - you are a _legend_! *happydance*